# Sharepoint 2013 : How can I ensure that list attachments are included in alert email?

Tags: 2013, alert, attachments

Is it possible to add the attachments to a list item in the alert emails or to at least make them visible in the email?  I've added attachment as a field but it displays in the list but not in the mail - problem is my mail goes to a group mailbox and I don't want people to have to go back and forth in order to complete a task.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is we cant send attachments from "Alert me" mails. Its better to use SharePoint designer simple workflow which can send emails with attachments.
Here is simple article which help you to create workflow in SPD.

[Send e-mails with attachments from SharePoint 2013 Workflow](https://plumsail.com/blog/2015/05/send-emails-with-attachments-from-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365-workflow/)